# Plot scatter with actual vs predicted values with seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn

This is how data frame `previsao3_df` looks like:

[image]

I want to plot a scatter where the regression line is designed by the values of column "`Previsão`".

```
scatter_poly2 = sns.lmplot(
    data = previsao3_df, 
    x = "X",
    y = "y",
    order = 2
)
```

Is generating this plot:

[image]

Is there a way to feed the plot with the predicted values `Previsão` ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing this a few minutes ago: what you need is described in [seaborn documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/regression.html). To solve your precise case simply:

```py
sns.regplot(x="y", y="Previsão", data=previsao3_df);
```

And you will get the correlation between your model predictions and actual training/fitting data. Please notice that there are several options in the documentation of [`regplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.regplot.html) and I invite you to explore that by yourself to master the package.